# How to align list elements in specific order

Tags: html, css

This is a simple issue but I seem to be stuck. I'm trying to align list elements by a specific order limited only by height of their parent.

Example: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yupikibice/edit?html,css,output)

So I'm trying to change the order of the items to go vertically instead of horizontally - Now the order is:

```
1   2

3
```

I'm trying to change it to:

```
1   3

2
```

The trick is to do  this without using JavaScript or CSS3 (It should be compatible to older browsers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great. No JavaScript and no CSS3? This can be easily achieved using either:

- Flexbox
- Columns

I can give you an example for both:

```css
.example-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 120px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -o-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}

.example-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<ul class="example-list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

For more elements:

[image]

Comment: Flexbox and Columns are not supported in IE9.

Comment: What if more elements are added? This fails then.

Comment: @Jay Added a preview.

Comment: @dark4p Yes, I said that earlier. I am not able to find a better solution. Will try anyways.

Comment: @Sahil How does this fail? Added preview for you.

Comment: @PraveenKumar When i run the code snippet i get the 2 cut and transferred  to the other column. I'm also hunting for other solutions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dark4p Did you see the preview that I have posted?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes i did. Also tried it in JSBin - It fails with 3 items but with 6 it's ok

Comment: @dark4p I tried with both 3 and 6 items and they look good right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, if I am adding 5 elements in first column I have 1,2,3 and then 4,5 in the next column.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, got it.